# Python DataFrame Apply conditions to row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dataframe which contains measurements, including positions.

I need to calculate the angle of the direction, which is done by ATAN(Y/X).

However, I need to add the condition of the sign of X and Y to account for the direction of the angle (which quadrant we are in).

So, I want to know how I can run through every row in the dataframe and for the column 'X'and 'Y' I need to :
 If X is positive and Y is positive then..
 If X is positive and Y is negative then..
 If X is negative and Y is positive then..
 If X is negative and Y is negative then..

I am struggling being able to apply this logic to a dataframe.

Anyone got an idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier is to use [`np.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html). This will take into account the sign of your two sides to give you an angle in `[-pi, pi]`.

---

To answer your actual question, you can use a nested if statements for instance:

```
if x >= 0:
     if y >= 0:
         # code
     else:  # y < 0
         # code
else:  # x < 0
     if y >= 0:
         # code
     else:  # y < 0
         # code
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including such logic manually, you might want to consider using the `arctan2` function from `numpy`; you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html). It handles the sign of the coordinates passed to it automatically.

In this case, assuming your columns in the `DataFrame` are named `X` and `Y` and the `DataFrame` is itself named `df`, you could just do `np.arctan2(df['Y'], df['X'])`.

Comment: Yes, such an elegant and easy solution! Thanks